# cannot retrieve and display data from the adapter into fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, adapter

I want to retrieve and display data from the recycler view into the fragment via an adapter, but the data is only stored in a bundle inside the adapter when I want to use it in a fragment, the data always doesn't appear.

My Adapter

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(BerandaFragment.KEY_NAME, 
        name.getText().toString());
        bundle.putString(BerandaFragment.KEY_EMAIL, 
        email.getText().toString());

        BerandaFragment berandaFragment = new BerandaFragment();
        berandaFragment.setArguments(bundle);


    }

    My Fragment
    cannot retrieve and display data on etDari
    I'm getting error in line :

    etDari = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_dari);

    Bundle bundle = getArguments();

    if (getArguments() != null) {
        etDari.setText(bundle.getString(KEY_EMAIL));
        etDari.setText(bundle.getString(KEY_EMAIL));
    }
   //        else {
   //            etDari.setText(KEY_NAME);
   //            etDari.setText(KEY_EMAIL);
   //        }
```

Comment: Code looks OK if I assume that you're displaying newly created instance of berandaFragment in FragmentManager?. You should be able to get arguments in `onCreate` method in BerandaFragment

Comment: how to make it ?? because i cannot understand what you mean

Comment: in `onClick` you're creating new instance of fragment and you're passing some arguments there, what are you doing later with newly created `berandaFragment`?

Comment: add your Fragment code

Comment: after the data is successfully saved in the bundle I want to send the data to be displayed in the EditText in berandaFragment.
but I always fail to get the data so that the data is only stored in a bundle and cannot be displayed in the EditText that is in berandaFragment

Comment: your fragment when called??

Comment: add your adpater code

Comment: can anyone help?? Because i dont understand pass data from activity to fragment :(

Answer (score 0):

```
From Your Adapter Pass Data to Fragment in a mentioned way :
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
replaceFragment(FragmentPurchaseWastageDetails.newInstance(requestList.get(position).getDate()));

Replace Fragment Code
-----------------------------
 public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        String backStateName = fragment.getClass().getName();
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        boolean fragmentPopped = false;
        try {
            fragmentPopped = manager.popBackStackImmediate(backStateName, 0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        /*
          if fragment not in back stack, create it.
         */
        if (!fragmentPopped && manager.findFragmentByTag(backStateName) == null) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.mainContainer, fragment, backStateName);
            ft.addToBackStack(backStateName);
            ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
        }
    }

--------------------------------------------------
To get data In Fragment (Make newInstance method in your fragment)

public static FragmentPurchaseWastageDetails newInstance(String date) {

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("date", date);
        FragmentPurchaseWastageDetails fragment = new FragmentPurchaseWastageDetails();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
--------------------------------------------------------------
In method of onViewCreated put the mentioned code to get data
------------------------------------------------------------

 private void getDatafromBundle() {
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            date = getArguments().getString("date");
        }
    }
```